# Authenticating ArcGIS Server Feature Service in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-10.2, arcgis-server, feature-service, authentication

I am trying to add a protected Arc layer to a QGIS project and have had no success.

What I have tried so far:

**1) Generate token using the token service url...**
[image]

**2) Create a QGIS authentication configuration...**
[image]

**3) Enter the service url...**
https://geodata-services.drillinginfo.com/arcgis/rest/services/Landtrac/DI_Landtrac_Units/FeatureServer
[image]

**When attempting to add the layer I get...**

Failed to retrieve service capabilities:
Error 499: Token Required

**However, if I append the token to the url with: url?token=*mytoken*, I am able to see the layer in the list...**

[image]

**But I am unable to add the layer to the map...
I receive error:**

2019-09-26T12:52:55     CRITICAL    Layer is not valid : The layer authcfg='10ph3f0' bbox='-1.13707e+07,3.75972e+06,-1.13549e+07,3.76784e+06' crs='EPSG:3857' filter='' url='https://geodata-services.drillinginfo.com/arcgis/rest/services/Landtrac/DI_Landtrac_Units/FeatureServer?token=*mytoken*/0' table="" sql= is not a valid layer and can not be added to the map. Reason: AFSProvider getLayerInfo failed

Answer (score 1):

I had what seemed to be the same errors, on a different server of course.
It worked after I reduced the url, deleting everything after /arcgis/rest/services/

If you try that it takes a long time to load the list of layers for me to choose the one I want, but that's better than not being able to use it at all.